# Transformation to compare many distributions with different means and variances

Tags: data-transformation, dataset, standardization

I have daily sales (total volume in dollars) from 200 stores of the same franchise, over two years. I would like to identify any store with anomalies or special patterns, which could be the sign of a fraud or just a different management (good or bad).

My problem is that the stores are not of the same size, hence the daily sales have different volumes. The distribution of the sales may need a transformation before comparison. I thought I could just divide the sales by their mean at each given store, and then proceed with comparisons such as the Anderson-Darling test. I am not sure of the statistical consequences of dividing by the mean. Another option is to standardize the distributions, but that loses information on the standard deviations.

What preprocessing approach would you recommend for the cleanest and most informative comparison between all these distributions?

Comment: Anomalies could well include anomalies in time. Otherwise, or for time series comparisons too, scaling each by their mean or median might help. Also, there may be (should be) further variables such as store size and population served.  How the stores do compared with expectations could be valuable information.